# How to change input type to password without key press delay

Tags: javascript, html

ok I have default text in an input field as "password" and when a key is pressed I want it to change to the input type "password".  But when I attempt this the input doesn't register my first key press but it registers all key presses after the input type switch.

```
function inputField(focus, inputValue, inputID){
// change inputID variable into pointer to the actual ID
var iD = document.getElementById(inputID);

// check if input has focus and handle default value changes, password field type changes, and font color changes.
if (focus == "on"){

    if(iD.value == inputValue){
        iD.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
        iD.style.color = "#b2b2b2";
    }
    iD.onkeypress = function(){
        if(iD.value == "password" || iD.value == "retype password"){
            iD.type = "password";
        }
        if (iD.value != "" && iD.value == inputValue){
                iD.value = "";
                iD.style.color = "#000000";
        }
    }
}else if(focus == "off"){
    if (iD.value == ""){
        if(iD.type == "password"){
            iD.type = "text";
        }
        iD.style.color = "#787878";
        iD.value = inputValue;
    }else if(iD.value == inputValue){
        iD.style.color = "#787878"
    }
}
}

<input
 id = "registerPassword"
 class = "loginSectionInput"
     type = "text"
 name = "rPassword"
 value = "password"
 onfocus = "inputField('on', 'password', this.id)"
 onblur = "inputField('off', 'password', this.id)"
 onchange = "formCheck('registerPassword')"
 />
```

Comment: Where is your keypress event? What element is iD?

Comment: please make a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 solves this problem for us with the **placeholder** attribute. No need to manage the events again...Please check some like following

```
<input type=password name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
```

Comment: how supported is that html 5 feature? edit: I just tried using the placeholder and it still shows up in the password "dots". edit again: nevermind I fixed it by removing the value attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different ways, some of them are listed here! hope i have help you

Let say you have field like-

```
<input type="text" id="mypswfield" name="mypswfield" />
```

**Way 1:**

On onClick even, you can replace it by using Jquery,

```
$('#mypswfield').replaceWith('<input type="password" id="mypswfield" />')
```

**Way 2:**

```
$("[name=fieldname]").attr("type", "password");
```

(Note: This is jquery function may issue in old IE so careful)

**Way 3:**
Create function

```
function txtField()
{
     if(document.getElementById('mypswfield').value=='')
     {
        document.getElementById('mypswfield').type='text';
        document.getElementById('mypswfield').value='Password';

     }

}
function txtPawd()
{
    document.getElementById('mypswfield').type='password'; 
    document.getElementById('mypswfield').value='';

}
```

HTML

```
<input id="mypswfield" onclick="txtField();" onblur="txtPawd();" name="mypswfield" type="text" value="Password">
```

Answer (score 0):

show you an example：

```
<html><head><script>function swithch(){
  alert("myText is ");
    var myText=document.getElementById("myId");
    alert("myText is "+myText);
    alert("myText is type "+myText.type);
    alert("myText is  value "+myText.value);
    myText.type='text';
    myText.value='56789';
  }</script></head><body>
 TT <input type="password" name="myText" id="myId" value="123456"/> <input type="button" name="switch" value="swithch" onclick="swithch()">
```

this code have been tested at google chrome.